# Multi user and guest accounts sign in WIN 8.1

Tags: windows-8.1, login, multiple-users

Guest account has been enabled, other user accounts created. However, the sign in page allows only one (the originally created) user to sign in.  I spent a considerable amount of time on the Web and chatted with a MS tech (who at the end tried to sell me for fee service) to deal with the issues. I found out that Win 8.1 (core) does not provide for user policy. All the other recommendation only repeated how to set up user and enable guest accounts but did not address the issue of other user sign in.

Having dealt with MS for almost 3 decades, I certainly am not shocked that MS will provide for useless bells and whistles but does not deal with some of the basics. Do I have to spent additional money to obtain WIN 8.1 PRO to obtain this functionality (together with all the other features I do not care about?

I would appreciate any suggestion, including those from MICROSOFT.

Comment: I'm quite confused by your question. Are you claiming that only one user can **ever** log into this computer, or are you saying that you cannot switch users? (for example, someone locks their computer, and someone else wants to log in while the other user is locked)

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are asking what to do if one person locks the computer and someone else needs on in that time (see Mike K's example in the comment above).

If that is the case, the solution is quite simple.  Next to the name of the user that has the computer locked, there is a back-arrow.  Click on that arrow, and it will take you to the list of all of the users.

If that is not what you wanted, please tell me.

Good luck!